# How to use a for loop on a Pandas dataframe and update column based on when another column value changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, row

Python beginner here. I'm working with a pandas dataframe and I want to loop over each row of data and change the values of a column based off another column's value. I have about 20 lines of code that do some stuff with the rows of data. I want to apply that code but for it to restart every time a value changes in a column. See example table below:

```
name      country  section  new_column
bob       US       1
jim       Canada   1    
christina US       2    
jason     UK       3    
kim       US       3    
chris     UK       4    
jimbo     Canada   4    
felicia   Canada   5
```

I would like to update my table to look as follows with a for loop:

```
name      country  section  new_column
bob       US       1        1
jim       Canada   1        2   
christina US       2        1   
jason     UK       3        1
kim       US       3        2
chris     UK       4        1
jimbo     Canada   4        2
felicia   Canada   5        1
```

So, let's say my table looks something like above. Every time column 'section' changes in value (from 1 to 2, 3 etc.), restart loop based on that column's value. I was hoping I could simply insert my lines of code below that structured for loop.

My pseudo code goes as follows:

1. for when column 'section' changes value, do the following:
2. my code
3. close loop?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: please provide a reproducible input (not an image) and the explicit matching output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby_cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('section').cumcount().add(1)
print(df)

# Output
        name country  section  new_column
0        bob      US        1           1
1        jim  Canada        1           2
2  christina      US        2           1
3      jason      UK        3           1
4        kim      US        3           2
5      chris      UK        4           1
6      jimbo  Canada        4           2
7    felicia  Canada        5           1
```

Comment: yes it did help for sure. Sorry for the late response. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help to solved your problem! :)